# "Swim team" vs "swimming team"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

My limited Google-fu shows both appear to be in use. Google Ngram is very puzzling, as it shows the two terms switched popularity positions. What are the differences between these two terms?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compare British and American corpora, the split is more distinct. While *swimming team* was the more common term in both a century ago, *swim team* has soared in popularity since the latter half of the 20th century, and is the far more prevalent form in the U.S.:

[image: Google NGram comparing 'swim team' and 'swimming team' in British and American corpora]

Still, it's not difficult to find *swimming team* in respectable American sources like [*Swimming World* magazine](https://www.swimmingworldmagazine.com/news/nc-state-grad-soren-dahl-awarded-jim-mckay-scholarship-by-ncaa/), and few would object to *swimming and diving team* over *swim and dive team* (many high school and university athletic departments combine the two sports into one program). In other words, there is no difference in meaning between a *swim team* and a *swimming team*, only in preference or familiarity.

I don't think the swing can be attributed to any one particular cause, and it isn't applicable to other sports or word pairs. *Swimming coach*, for example, has been more resilient in AmE vs. *swim coach*:

[image: Google NGram comparing AmE/BrE use of 'swim coach' and 'swimming coach']

The *-ing* remains safely ensconced in many sports: there are far more [*cycling* teams than *cycle* teams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cycle%20team%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccycling%20team%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccycle%20team%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccycling%20team%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3), and I do not think *boxing*, *fishing*, or *cheerleading* are in any danger of changing, for example. On the other hand, I'm perfectly fine with *ski instructor*, *hunt club*, *skate coach*, or *snowboard helmet* where some might insist upon the progressive forms.